# How do I fix this C++ program that *tries* to convert US dollars to Chinese yuan and South Korean won?

Tags: c++

This is the program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    double dollars;
    double won=dollars/0.00093;
    double yuan=dollars/0.16;

    cout<<"Enter the amount of dollars you would like converted:"<<endl;
    cin>>dollars; 

    cout<<"South Korean Won: "<<fixed<<won<<endl;
    cout<<"Chinese Yuan: "<<fixed<<yuan<<endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Whenever I try this, it comes out as 
"South Korean Won: 0.000000
Chinese Yuan: 0.000000". 
What should I change?

Comment: your program has undefined behavior, dollars is not initialized when you do the conversion. clang++ gives the following warning: `main.cpp:8:16: warning: variable 'dollars' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]`

Comment: I moved the "double won=dollars/0.00093;
    double yuan=dollars/0.16;" below the "cin>>dollars;" and the program worked, thank you!

Comment: If you want to define the conversions before initializing the values, you can use a function or lambda for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the order like this:

```
cout<<"Enter the amount of dollars you would like converted:"<<endl;
cin>>dollars; 
double won=dollars/0.00093; 
double yuan=dollars/0.16;
```

Your version has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), because you are using uninitialized variable `dollars`.

Answer (score 0):

Define won and yuan after you input dollar from cin, else won and yuan contains grabage

```
int main()
{
double dollars;

cout<<"Enter the amount of dollars you would like converted:"<<endl;
cin>>dollars;
double won=dollars/0.00093;
double yuan=dollars/0.16; 

cout<<"South Korean Won: "<<fixed<<won<<endl;
cout<<"Chinese Yuan: "<<fixed<<yuan<<endl; 

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 double won=dollars/0.00093;
```

means "create variable 'won' and initialize it with value of expression `dollars/0.00093`.
While your idea how it should work exists as a paradigm in some programming languages, it's not how C++ works. You have to find value of dollars before making such statement in C++.